# Region detection in a grayscale image

Tags: image-processing

I would like to identify the white spots in a greyscale image and calculate the area among other things.

[image]

I have tried to identify the white spots with:

```
markers = MaxDetect[GaussianFilter[img01, 60], Padding -> 1];
HighlightImage[img01, markers, Method -> {"DiskMarkers", 5}]
```

[image]

Is there a way to find the edge and calculate the area?

I would also like to scale it up to a larger picture with many spots, which seems to bring a lot of problems

Comment: Have you tried using a high pass filter?

Comment: I think the first thing is to decide what you want to measure. What *exactly* counts as the white spot? How should one decide whether a pixel counts as part of the white spot or not?

Answer (score 5):

Taking a look at the histogram of the image, one can see that the white pixel intensities ranges roughly between 0.85 and 1.

[image: Image histogram]

It is safe to assume that the pixel intensity on the upper bound corresponds to the brightest spots since it has the highest distribution. Therefore, Binarizing it with a very fine threshold of 0.99 and then using median filter to remove the salt noise we get the following:

```
MedianFilter[Binarize[img, 0.99], 4]
```

[image: Binarized picture]

Further processing (Calculating the area of white spot) should be fairly simple from this point.